# Chrome history not properly synchronized

Tags: google-chrome, sync, history

I've had to switch a lot between different computer recently and realized that Google Chrome's history synchronization feature doesn't work properly for me.

What I've tested so far:

I had the latest stable version of Chrome running on three devices. I was logged in with my google account and history synchronization was enabled in the settings as well. I opened the history, and opened different websites on each device. I waited a while and sadly no synchronization and merging happened. What's strange, though, when I opened one page on my android phone which is also connected with my Google account, the page appeared immediately in the history on all other devices.

After that I even tried new fresh versions of Chrome with a newly created Google account with no success.

Please enlighten me whether I've been doing something wrong or if the feature is not intended to work that way. (synchronize and merge the history of multiple devices into one complete history)

## **EDIT 1:**

I was using the encryption with a sync passphrase instead of just my google password. (see attached picture)
I found out that if you choose this option, Google doesn't synchronize the history across devices as stated [on this support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181035)

In order to switch to the first option, I reset my Chrome synchronization to enable the history sync across all devices.
**However**, it still doesn't work properly I only get the main sites listed (e.g. Google, Stackoverflow) but not all visited sites (e.g. stackoverflow.com/posts/*** etc. ) in detail.
The question is: Is that intended? Do you get every visited page synced?

## **EDIT 2:**

I was using the Chrome extension "Better History" which was causing the consolidation of the visited pages from other devices. After disabling the extension everything looks as wanted so that the matter can be seen as closed.

[image]

Comment: next time, please post your solution as an answer. this way, your question doesn't come up as unanswered

Answer (score 0):

- Reset Sync by going to the Google Dashboard.
- Log out of Chrome on all your devices (PC, Mac, smartphone, etc)
- Quit Chrome (kill Chrome process if necessary)
- Run Chrome again and you should be asked to sign in to your account.
- Once all accounts are signed in, the history should sync across all devices

[image: Reset Sync]

Comment: The google dashboard is available at https://myaccount.google.com/dashboard